# Alternate regex with -SDR?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex in my c#:

```
(?<!\w)M20A\w+
```

Actual code:

```
string regex = $@"(?<!\w){prefix}\w+";
```

Notice the prefix var matches strings such as M20A and X50G.

It perfectly matches the following cases:

```
M20A0820
M20A1234
M20A7U8V
```

But now I got a new requirement from the business to match, for example:

```
M20A-SDR
```

It will be the prefix followed by the exact string "-SDR". Not just a dash followed by 3 alphanumerics, but literally "-SDR". The existing matches need to still work, but prefix + "-SDR" must also be matched.

What would be the regex that would match the following:

```
M20A0820
M20A1234
M20A7U8V
M20A-SDR
```

Comment: Please let us know one thing: if a result that is equal to the prefix only a valid match? Is `M20A` an expected match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
string regex = $@"(?<!\w){prefix}\w*(?:-SDR)?";
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cw%29M20A%5cw*%28%3f%3a-SDR%29%3f&i=M20A0820%0d%0aM20A1234%0d%0aM20A7U8V%0d%0aM20A-SDR).

Or, to match as a whole word, you may use word boundaries:

```
string regex = $@"\b{prefix}\w*(?:-SDR)?\b";
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbM20A%5cw*%28%3f%3a-SDR%29%3f%5cb&i=M20A0820%0d%0aM20A1234%0d%0aM20A7U8V%0d%0aM20A-SDR)

The `\b`  word boundary at the start will work if all the values in `prefix` start with a word char, a letter, digit or `_`. The word boundary at the end will make sense if after `-SDR`, there can be no more word chars.

The `(?:-SDR)?` will match a `-SDR` string optonally.

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `M20A` - a literal string
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars
- `(?:-SDR)?` - a non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 times (as there is a `?` after it) an `-SDR` substring
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: This does not match `M20A-SDR` because it requires a further character before the `-SDR`. Perhaps a better solution would be `\bM20A(\w+|-SDR)\b` as it satisfies the requirement: 'the prefix followed by the exact string "-SDR"'

Comment: @iakobski Now, it matches as expected. We can avoid the alternation group here as `\w` does not match `-`, and this reduces backtracking a tiny bit. Well, if the prefix itself is not an expected result, then yes, we'll need the alternation.

Comment: OK, cool. But it still allows prefix + some other characters + -SDR which I don't think the OP's requirements allows. But I could be wrong.